# What is the use of Wordpress APIs?

Tags: wordpress

I saw in wordpress some APIs being published for developers. What could a developer gain by using those APIs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you've taken API to mean something similar to what Flickr and Vimeo do, which they are not. They are simply ways for you to access and ammend core functionality of the Wordpress platform, so as to bend it to do what ever it is you need it to do.

There are ways to pull data from your blog to a mobile devise, but that is a very different question.

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress API are for those that want to develop a theme, or writing custom plugins for Wordpress.

Either way, you can use to integrate Wordpress in your exisiting php site, using the powerful backend as an administration tool and the using the API to retrieve the content and present it in your (already) website.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Integrating_WordPress_with_Your_Website

Comment: can this be of any use in getting content for a mobile app?

Comment: It's better, if you use a plugin that convert your blog in a site for mobile, (http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wptouch/, this is for Iphone). For a mobile app, you can always write a page on the server that extract only the information needed and format for a mobile browser. But I think this is not the right way to do it.